# Need to drop cells in a dataframe that are type 'O'

Tags: python, string, dataframe, object, type-conversion

I have a dataframe with one column and more than 1000 rows that represent invoices its separated by a cell with no value. they are 'O' type, so I can't fill them with fillna. The thing is that I transpose the dataframe and I need that the code can look for this non value cell and make it a new row in the data frame, so every invoice will be represented by a row. I can't do that.

```
def separar_facturas(df_final, col_vacia):
    df_fact = pd.DataFrame()  # Creamos un dataframe vacío para ir agregando las nuevas filas
    for index, row in df.iterrows():  # Recorremos todas las filas del dataframe
        if row[col_vacia] == '':  # Si encontramos una celda vacía en la columna indicada
            fila_factura = row[:col_vacia]  # Tomamos los datos de la factura hasta la celda vacía
            fila_factura = fila_factura.to_frame().transpose()  # Convertimos los datos en un dataframe con una sola fila
            df_fact = pd.concat([df_fact, fila_factura])  # Agregamos la fila al dataframe final
            fila_restante = row[col_vacia+1:]  # Tomamos los datos restantes de la fila
            while len(fila_restante.dropna()) > 0:  # Mientras haya datos en la fila
                if pd.isnull(fila_restante[0]):  # Si encontramos otra celda vacía
                    fila_restante = fila_restante[1:]  # Pasamos a la siguiente celda
                    continue
                fila_nueva = pd.concat([fila_factura, fila_restante[:col_vacia]])  # Tomamos los datos de la nueva fila hasta la celda vacía
                fila_nueva = fila_nueva.to_frame().transpose()  # Convertimos los datos en un dataframe con una sola fila
                df_fact = pd.concat([df_fact, fila_nueva])  # Agregamos la fila al dataframe final
                fila_restante = fila_restante[col_vacia+1:]  # Tomamos los datos restantes de la fila
    df_fact = df_fact.reset_index(drop=True)  # Reseteamos el índice del dataframe final
    return df_fact

df_facturas = separar_facturas(df_final, 'Columna 1')
```

I tried with that function but it didn't work, it fails in this line: fila_restante = fila_restante[col_vacia+1:]  # Tomamos los datos restantes de la fila.

I tried to convert everything to str, but either work. Please help me with ideas.

I hope that I can make the new dataframe in which every row represent an invoice.

Here is an Example:
[image: Example of what I have]

And this is what I Need:

[image: Example of what I need]

columns 89 and 179 are type 'O', so It didn't work if I read the whole column until a null value, and then, create a new row with all the following information.

Comment: Can you share a *minimal reproducible example* and the matching expected output ?